# Is it possible to use the Milkman iOS In-App Purchase Extension for Adobe AIR for pledge?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

I've got an AIR app (AS3) and I'd like to add a button that allows the user to give money to our company.

I saw the Milkman Plugin "https://www.milkmanplugins.com/ios-in-app-purchase-extension-for-adobe-air" for putting a in app feature in an AIR app.

Can I use it for this purpose (pledge) ? Do you think I should use it or something else ?

Thx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apples policy is unclear

“21.1 Apps that include the ability to make donations to recognized charitable organizations must be free

21.2 The collection of donations must be done via a web site in Safari or an SMS”

This is a better thread-

[How can I handle donations through iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744252/ios-how-can-i-handle-donations)