# How to Collect Charitable Donations from a Native iOS App?

Tags: in-app-purchase, payment, applepay, donations

I am working on an app that needs to have functionality to collect charitable donations.

[Apple Pay on the Web: Acceptable Use Guidelines](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Documentation/Apple_Pay_Guidelines/ApplePayGuidelines.pdf)

I found at the above link that collection of charitable donations is prohibited with Apple Pay.

[App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

Here in Section 3.2.2 it states that you cant use In-App Purchases to collect charitable donations.

I have found another StackOverflow post that brushes on my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744252/ios-how-can-i-handle-donations).

So, according to the Rules and Regulations, I know that I cant use in app Purchases for Charitable Donations. I also know that I can't use Apple Pay.

What is the best way to prompt a user to donate without forcing them to manually enter all of their payment info into an online form?

I have looked a little bit at Apple Wallet, but the only way that would work is if someone already has their card set up and it will help AutoFill the information. Correct me if I am wrong, but this is what I have understood.

Additionally, is there any reason Apple has given as to why it is so difficult to give charitable donations? A coworker is doing the same thing for Android and hasn't run into nearly as many roadblocks as I have.

Comment: I don't think there is a way. Forbidding this was Apple's intent, and they can simply deny you acceptance.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Do you know where they stated that this was their intent?

Comment: I think I've heard about something similar to this too unfortunately when I worked on another app. BUT, I've often seen "things" sold with the disclaimer that all proceeds go to a certain cause. Could you guys make a special hat or skin or something of little value that you could the sell to the users?

Answer (score 6):

The answer is no. Apple doesn't let you its in their rules:

> 21) Charities and contributions Apps that include the ability to make
>   donations to recognized charitable organizations must be free The
>   collection of donations must be done via a web site in Safari or an
>   SMS

You can call the app review department in California: (408) 996-1010 OR (512) 674-2000, but I highly doubt you'll get any luck.

My advice would be the following:

Get creative and find some simple feature/service that you can add to your service that you can sell with an IAP/Apple Wallet that provides some simple benefit to the member, and you market that as all proceeds going towards the cause your raising money for. As long as your actually delivering some digital good within your app, I don't ***think*** Apple can dictate what you actually do with the money, you just can't take money for nothing using their service.

See this similar post: [How can I handle donations through iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744252/ios-how-can-i-handle-donations?rq=1)

You might want to check section 21 more closely. If your app is free to use you may be able to get around it. Or just call the review team directly. That would be fun.

Comment: Actually now, Apple will allow you to get donations with in App.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk Care to post a link?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk however, it seems to require a native app.  `4.7 Apps may contain or run code that is not embedded in the binary (e.g. HTML5-based games, bots, etc.), as long as...(4) does not provide access to ...charitable donations`

Answer (score 4):

Apple accepts charitable donations in-app now. You must sign up using Benevity.

Details are at https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/nonprofits/

Comment: Does anyone know if the app can create an apple pay donation button that would donate to a third party nonprofit registered with Apple/Benevity? Or do you have to be that entity in order to accept donations within the app for that nonprofit?
E.g. can my app accept donations to Red Cross? I would assume the donation goes straight to Red Cross. If so why would I not be allowed to collect for them within my app?

Comment: @batthis 3.2.1(vi) of the app store guidelines states "Approved nonprofits may fundraise directly within their own apps or third-party apps, provided those fundraising campaigns adhere to all App Review Guidelines and offer Apple Pay support." So I would assume yes as long as those non profits are Apple approved (Benevity). Did you end up finding an answer as I am doing the same thing and my app is not a non profit but caters for non profits.

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime, Apple allowed donations by using Apple Pay within your app and website:

https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-pay-nonprofits/

So this should be doable without web views within iOS.

Answer (score 3):

Apple does not allow in-app donations.  You can redirect to a website (eg. PayPal), but this must happen **outside the app**.

Using Safari View Controller to open a webview **within the app** will be rejected.

Instead, force the URL to be handled by the device's default web browser - they will allow this.

Answer (score 0):

As per Apple's app-store rules, you cannot collect charities or donations from the native iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

All is correct, you cannot accept money from within the app.

HOWEVER, as per feedback from my conservation app being rejected, was that they will NOT accept any payments within the app for charitable contributions.  But, if you takes your customer to an external link, via webview (must be webview and not built into app) and from this webview site, they can create payments.  If the charity you want to support has a website that accepts contributions, you can direct them there via with webview.